# Switching ResourceDictionary when user selects it from a settings page in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have created a few ResourceDictionaries in my Windows Phone app and I added this code in the App.xaml.cs file to load the themes:

```
private void LoadDictionary()
{
    var dictionaries = Resources.MergedDictionaries;
    dictionaries.Clear();
    string source = String.Format("/MyApp;component/Themes/Theme2.xaml");
    var themeStyles = new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri(source, UriKind.Relative) };
    dictionaries.Add(themeStyles);
}
```

This works fine when I change the code and recompile it but what I want and have not been able to figure out is; how to load a dictionary when a user selects a theme from a settings page?

The way I am setting the style to the TextBox in the XAML is like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Count" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Center" InputScope="Number">
  <TextBox.Style>
      <StaticResource ResourceKey="InputTextBox" />
  </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would normally do this using a DynamicResource (see this article [WPF Switch Color Theme](http://bit.ly/JnW7fq)), but unfortunately we don't have that luxury in Windows Phone.

My only suggestion would be to use a Global class with properties for the things you want to swap, and then handle the swaping manually through a SetTheme() method.